MailKit C# "MyExampledomain:DummyPerson <DummyPerson@mail.MyExampledomain.com>" results in empty from address
MailKit C# MyExampledomain:DummyPerson <DummyPerson@mail.MyExampledomain.com> results in empty "From" address
I am using Mailkit library (C#) to retrieve emails via IMAP

for an address format like - MyExampledomain:DummyPerson <DummyPerson@mail.MyExampledomain.com>

The code below gives empty "From" address.
foreach (var item in Folder)
{
    // retrieve From Address
    var FromAddress = item.From.ToString();
}


You mean? "MyExampledomain:DummyPerson" <DummyPerson@mail.MyExampledomain.com>. All your tries showing the format are invalid. It should be "displayname" <emailaddress>. If its not formatted in that way MailKIt might have a parsing problem. WHen trying your examples with a MailboxAddress.Parse call i get ParseExceptions.

yes the format is - "MyExampledomain:DummyPerson" DummyPerson@mail.MyExampledomain.com

If the "name" component of an email address contains a ':', then it NEEDS to be quoted. This is not a MimeKit/MailKit bug, it is the email specifications that demand this.

Well, I have received emails in this format from many marketing companies.
